# how to must validate all textboxs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

This is fill in blanks for online test. so i need to must fill all textbox.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/NfcxX/191/)**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="question_form" class="cmxform" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control fillblank boxes" placeholder="Type Here" name="24" id="4"  required="true" >
      <input type="text" class="form-control fillblank boxes" placeholder="Type Here" name="24" id="5"  required="true" >
      <input type="text" class="form-control fillblank boxes" placeholder="Type Here" name="24" id="6"   required="true" >
```

Comment: [Use different names](http://jsfiddle.net/NfcxX/192/)

Comment: @Tushar : yeah its correct.. but this is group question...so i need same name for question.  any other way to validate?

Comment: find the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NfcxX/203/)

Comment: If you have the `required` attribute in the HTML, then you do not need to declare the `required` rule within the `rules` object.  However, no matter how rules are assigned, you **must** have a *unique* `name` on every input element or this plugin will not work properly.  There is no workaround for this mandate; it's how the plugin keeps track of everything.   http://jsfiddle.net/z4fyh2xh/

Answer (score 0):

name must have unique value, use `name` as array, try this

```
<form action="" method="post" id="question_form" class="cmxform" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control fillblank boxes" placeholder="Type Here" name="24[0]" id="4"  required="true" >
  <input type="text" class="form-control fillblank boxes" placeholder="Type Here" name="24[1]" id="5"  required="true" >
  <input type="text" class="form-control fillblank boxes" placeholder="Type Here" name="24[2]" id="6"   required="true" >
```